Replacing a simple color fill with flags (raster or svg fill) in a legend print layout in QGIS
If I just add a map legend, then it is obvious that in the legend the signs will appear as on the map itself, with a simple fill:


So, is there a way to replace this simple fill  with raster or SVG fill, with flags of countries, to make it look something like this?:



For an automatic legend to have an entry for each country separately, each of the country polygons must be on a separate layer: legend entries are per layer, not per feature. To do so, use Split vector layer. Alternative: use Categorized layer rendering, so you get an entry for each feature in the legend.
Create a legend, where now you have an entry for each country. To change the default rectangular symbol, in the Item Properties of the legend double click this symbol. In the window that opens, check the box Custom Symbol and double click again on the symbol dropdown menu. You come to Item Properties > Symbol Settings, that looks like the regular Layer Stylig. Here, you can select/create any kind of symbol, e.g. SVG Fill or Raster Image fill.


The question is how you can automate this, but that would rather be anohter question and you should post it separately.


Thanks for the answer. Can I ask it in comments, rather than create a new question? Because it looks like a pretty time-consuming thing to do it manually, layer by layer ( I mean, how to automatize the whole process).

You probably won't get answers in the comment. Better ask a new question to draw attention to it.

Ok, thanks! I'm creating a new one!
